# Android main activity crash - FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am getting a null pointer exception when trying to run my app. It seems ok in the manifest xml file. here is the activity java code:

```
package com.shale.activities;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.OnErrorListener;
import com.shale.services.DBConnection;
import com.shale.services.Login;
import com.shale.shaleapp.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Context context;
    private Button loginBtn;
    private Intent mainPage = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
    private EditText userEmail;
    private EditText userPass;
    private LoginButton fbLoginBtn;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         DBConnection.initialize(this);
         loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
         userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);
         userPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
         fbLoginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
         context = this;


         loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Login login = new Login(userEmail.getText().toString(), userPass.getText().toString());
                boolean userAllowed = login.loginUser();
                if(userAllowed) 
                {
                    startActivity(mainPage);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Invalide email and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
         });

          fbLoginBtn.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener()
          {
               @Override
               public void onError(FacebookException error)
               {
                   Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
               }
          });

          // set permission list, Don't foeget to add email
          fbLoginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
          // session state call back event
          fbLoginBtn.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback()
          {

              @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
              {
                  if (session.isOpened())
                  {
                      Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
                      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                      {
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response)
                          {
                              if (user != null) 
                              { 
                                  Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ user.getId());
                                  Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                                  Login login = new Login(user.asMap().get("email").toString(), "facebookPass");
                                  logIn();
                              }
                          }
                      });
                  }

              }
          });
    }

     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }

     private void logIn() 
     {
         Intent mainPage = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
         startActivity(mainPage);
     }
```

}

here is the manifest xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.shale.shaleapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.shale.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.shale.activities.MainPage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_page" >
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/fb_app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the logCat output:

```
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.shale.shaleapp/com.shale.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3301)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at com.shale.activities.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:33)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
05-06 06:25:01.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1690):     ... 11 more
```

It indicates that there is problem with the MainActivity, but I just can't find it. Thanks!!!

Comment: What's in line 33 in your `MainActivity`?

Comment: this  `private Intent mainPage = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);` causing issue i think. plz move it inside onCreate after setContentView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of

```
private Intent mainPage = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
```

Move it to `onCreate()`

Comment: Yup, Just private Intent mainPage; to global declaration;  and initialize it in onCreate...as mainPage = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);

Answer (score 4):

In the following line of code,

```
    private Intent mainPage = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
```

you are trying to pass the context of the MainActivity (i.e., this) before even initiating the activity. So you could just declare the intent before onCreate if you want it to be global and define it inside onCreate so that it gets a proper context to start another activity.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is not called yet, so using `this` will give nullpointerexception. Try not initialize `mainPage`. Instead, move your

```
Intent mainPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainPage.class);
```

to just right before the line `startActivity(mainPage);`

Comment: if you move the code before startActivity(mainPage) you should use activity context like mainPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainPage.class);

Comment: Yes, that is an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Intent mainPage;// before onCreate() inside activity class
```

In onCreate()

```
mainPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainPage.class);
```

You got NullPointerException Because you initialized you intent before onCreate();